# VS Code Error Pop-up when i'm writing code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code for web development and I don't know if it's with the last 2 updates, but my VS Code is showing pop up error messages on almost every line, e.g: if i'm typing `overflow: hidden;` it shows me a message as soon as i type just `o`. And then whole screen keeps scrolling up and down and it gets really hard to continue my coding. Is there anyway to ignore or turn off these messages? It'd be a great help. Thank You in advance. See here in the image. As soon as I typed input and didn't even save its showing me to place curly brackets there. And my cursor gets so annoying and messy.

[image: See here in the image. As soon as i typed input and didn't even save its showing me to place curly brackets there. And my cursor gets so annoying and messy]

I hope now you understand. It tell me to put a colon at the end of my instruction but at least it should let me complete it, and it takes my cursor out of the braces and it keeps getting out even if I click somewhere else.

[image: image1]

Comment: `overflow: hidden;` needs to be inside curly braces `{}`

Comment: I know.. But it doesn't let me complete. When i write 'o' of overflow it tells me to put a semi-colon at the end.

Comment: You need to put `{` after the selector `input`.

Comment: Edited my question. Hope you'll understand now.